# How to use semicolon as a separating character in ::csv::read2matrix command?

Tags: csv, tcl

I am using these two packages in my TCL script, CSV and `struct::matrix`.

And using this command `::csv::read2matrix  ? -alternate ?  chan m {sepChar ,} {expand none}`

Here I want to use semicolon as separating character but the interpreter is interpreting semicolon as "end of statement". And because of that it doesn't recognize `{expand none}` as a part of the command.

I hope I explained my problem. Any way to use semicolon as a separating character? I have tried using it between double quotes.

And is it possible to use blank space as a separator? I tried " " but didn't work.

My code is something like this:

```
proc updatecsv {} {

set csvfile "pathto/mycsvfile/csv.csv"

set value "6 field"

struct::matrix data
set f [open $csvfile]
csv::read2matrix $f data \; auto
close $f

set updateddata {}
foreach key [data get column 0] {
    lappend updateddata $value
}

data add column $updateddata

set f [open $csvfile w]
csv::writematrix data $f
close $f
}
```

My csv is in the format:

```
1;101;1 value;2 value;3 value;1 value;4 value;
2;101;1 value;2 value;3 value;1 value;4 value;
3;101;1 value;2 value;3 value;1 value;4 value;
4;101;1 value;2 value;3 value;1 value;4 value;
5;101;1 value;2 value;3 value;1 value;4 value;
```

I have to add one more column

Comment: What is the actual code you're using?

Comment: I just tried your code and it adds the new column just fine, but uses a comma instead of semicolon as separator in the output, like this: `1,101,1 value,2 value,3 value,1 value,4 value,,6 field` (and so on). What are you getting?

Comment: @Hoodiecrow On using ";" and {;} the interpreter just replaces all ; with , in my file, just similar to what you are getting ('1,101,1 value,2 value,3 value,1 value,4 value,,6 field'). And on the use of \; interpreter gives an error 'illegal separator character "\;", is a string'

Comment: Yes, you need to write back to the file with the invocation `csv::writematrix data $f {;}` (i.e. telling it to use semicolons when writing the csv data to file), otherwise you're going to get commas in the output. `\;` or `";"` should work as well.

Comment: @Hoodiecrow This seems like a good idea. I can again replace all the commas with with semi-colon at the time of writing to the file.  I tried it and it worked. Thanks. :) One last thing, can I skip first line while reading or writing?

Comment: Not with `read2matrix` / `writematrix` themselves, you'd have to add a filtering channel in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That “command” you're looking at is a *formal* parameter list, not an invocation. The arguments *not* in braces are mandatory; the parts between `?`s and in `{`braces`}` are optional. The default values for some of those arguments are the second word of those braced bits. To use it with semicolons as separators, you do:

```
set chan [open $someFilename]
set m [struct::matrix]
::csv::read2matrix chan m ";"
close $chan
# Do stuff with $m now...
```

Remember: `;` is a Tcl metacharacter for “end of command” (just like newline) so to use it as a normal character you *must* quote it. Putting it in double-quotes is ideal.

This is all just for reading values in. When writing them out, you *also* have to specify the delimiter if you don't want the default (a `,`).

```
::csv::writematrix $m $chan ";"
```

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I did use double quotes. But it didn't help, it replaced all ; with , in the file instead.

Comment: @hoodie mentioned this point for writematrix command. It solved my problem.

Comment: @Abhi We were all missing that you were writing it back out again. A critical detail that one.

Comment: I agree. I added it later for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the semi-colon with `\`. You could use either `{\;}` or `"\\;"`

Comment: Or even just `";"` or `{;}`.

Comment: The question says semi-colon between the double quotes is already tried.

Comment: @VarunLakkur: the OP possibly tried it in an invalid invocation, such as `{sepChar ";"}` (which would not work). There is no reason why `";"` shouldn't work when used correctly.

Comment: @VarunLakkur I tried all of them already. But interpreter says 'illegal separator character "\;", is a string'.

Comment: @Hoodiecrow I have added my code, you can have a look.